# SQL - Converting datetime format to 12 hours format with hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query like,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 100) AS TwelveHH
```

output of the above query is `Sep 26 2012  6:02PM` & i want to get the Hours from the above query means, i will use the query like,

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 100), 7) AS getTime
```

output of the above query is `6:02PM`.

But, i want output with ***seconds*** like `6:02:19PM` - `(hh:mm:ss)` format.

How to i get ***hh:mm:ss*** format?

Comment: When asking about SQL question you need to specify target server(s). For instance, there is no `GETDATE()` function in MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several years ago I wrote [this handy guide](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-valid-styles-for-converting-datetime-to-string.html) which still helps me today - mostly because there is no way I am ever going to memorize what all of the different style numbers mean:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 22), 11));
```

In my time zone this returns:

```
9:12:55 AM
```

This isn't *precisely* what you want - you can use `REPLACE` or `STUFF` if it's really important to remove that space. e.g.

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 22), 11)), ' ', '');
```

In SQL Server 2012, you will be able to do this easier - you can format using parity with C#:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'h:mm:ss tt');
```

**EDIT** Based on new and changed requirements in the comments below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 109)
 + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 22), 11));
```

Result:

```
Sep 26 2012 10:03:52 AM
```

Comment: Hi @Aaron Bertrand... Suppose i want output like `Sep 26 2012  7:14:33 PM ` means, how to i achieve this? .... When i use this query `SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(30), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));` , it will display the output like `Sep 26 2012  7:17PM`

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju so now you want a completely different format than the one you asked for in the question?

Comment: Yes @AaronBertrand... In my scenario, i am using **CASE** statement to check _Hour_ difference, if that is with in 24 hours means, i want to get the output like HH:MM:SS else `Sep 26 2012 7:14:33 PM`

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand... Thanks for your new answer... Oh, You just concordinate `109` date format & your format...

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),108) AS getTime
```

Comment: Hi @Lamak.. Thanks for your reply.. Your query will return 24 hours format.. but i need 12 hours format with hh:mm:ss